# how to insert item with attachments to normal list in office 365 using asp.net c#?

Tags: development, office-365, csom, asp.net

I am trying to add item to Office 365 list item, and I did use the below code:

```
public string PostingDeliveryNote(string ProjectName, string SupplierName, string DN_No , string PONo, 
        string HWSalesContractNo, string PackingListNo,FileStream FileName )
    {

        using (ClientContext CContext = new ClientContext(WebUrl))
        {
            CContext.Credentials = AuthinticatingUser();
            List TargetedList = CContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Delivery_Note");
            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem newItem = TargetedList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

            newItem["Title"] = ProjectName;
            newItem["SupplierName"] = SupplierName;
            newItem["DN No"] = DN_No;
            newItem["PONo"] = PONo;
            newItem["HWSalesContractNo"] = HWSalesContractNo;
            newItem["PackingListNo"] = PackingListNo;

            newItem.Update();
            CContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        return "Item added successfully";

    }
```

but I was not able to attach files to the list.
any suggestions?

I need to extend this function to get save attachments.

the below is the updated solution for the method:

```
 public string PostingDeliveryNote(string ProjectName, string SupplierName, string DN_No , string PONo, 
        string HWSalesContractNo, string PackingListNo,string FileName,string FilePath)
    {

        using (ClientContext CContext = new ClientContext(WebUrl))
        {
            CContext.Credentials = AuthinticatingUser();
            List TargetedList = CContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Delivery_Note");
            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem newItem = TargetedList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

            newItem["Title"] = ProjectName;
            newItem["SupplierName"] = SupplierName;
            newItem["DNNo"] = DN_No;
            newItem["PONo"] = PONo;
            newItem["HWSalesContractNo"] = HWSalesContractNo;
            newItem["PackingListNo"] = PackingListNo;
            newItem.Update();
            CContext.ExecuteQuery();

            int LastID = newItem.Id;
            ///////////////////////////// Uploading the attachments
            ///

            newItem.Update();
            AttachmentCreationInformation attachmentCreateinfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
            attachmentCreateinfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath));
            attachmentCreateinfo.FileName = FileName;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Attachment att = newItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachmentCreateinfo);
            CContext.ExecuteQuery();

            ///////////////////////////////
        }
        return "New Item added Succfully";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add attachment to list item like the below:

```
        newItem.Update();
        AttachmentCreationInformation attachmentCreateinfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
        attachmentCreateinfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test.docx"));
        attachmentCreateinfo.FileName = "test.docx";
        Attachment att = newItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachmentCreateinfo);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: thanks a lot dear, it was great help <3\